# What’s wrong with my aloe?

Tags: diagnosis

[image]

Lately I’ve moved it to the patio since the summer began. The leaves started turning pale and are becoming flat. There are few brown spots on the leaves. I water it once in two weeks and it gets ample sunlight. I live in Colorado and the temperatures are high 80s. Please help!

Comment: I would guess that it got rained on and water that collected in the middle is causing it to rot.  Happened to mine a few years back under similar conditions.

Comment: It hasn’t rained for a while.. maybe it’s a sunburn.. I’ll move it indoors.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Plants that are indoors can not be taken out of doors and into the sun.  Aloe most certainly loves sun but if it has been grown indoors then it needs acclimation before allowed in direct sun longer than...5 minutes the first day.  This is too much sun.  Get it out of the sun and into the shade.  Do not over water or give fertilizer until your aloe responds.

If you have an awning or a porch roof that is where this plant would be happier right now.  Far more light than indoors.  Your aloe will be able to make more food for itself. Bring your plant indoors way before a chance of freeze.

Because you are in Colorado you will never want to plant your aloe out of doors.  The best thing for indoor plants is to go out on a fully covered porch for a few months when there is no chance of frost.  More light, the plants make more food for themselves, store it for winter...really revives house plants.  But a plant not used to direct sun either out of doors or even through a window can easily be killed placing it direct sun.

This is too much sun.  Sun burn.  The epidermis of indoor or plants in the shade is thinner than the epidermis of the same plants accustomed to direct sun.  Similar to 'sunscreen'?  Takes weeks to acclimate plants to direct sun, beginning with 5 minutes for a few days, doubling that for a few days, doubling that for a few days until your plant has a thicker epidermis and can handle direct sun. The sun has fried some of the chloroplasts that do photosynthesis, thus the pale yellow color.

Answer (score 1):

Aloe's don't like much direct sun light, try some place where it gets plenty of indirect sunlight

Answer (score 0):

Looks like too much water .i water mine once a month inside and not at all outside. The aloe I have came from the desert of Arizona it is in an 18 gallon terracotta  pot and stands 5 foot tall and loves sun. Yours looks like it is sun burned, the new leaves that emerge will be more sun resistant. You might think of changing the soil to a cactus quick draining type soil